# How to generate a list-column holding named-vectors, when grouping by other data frame variables?

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, tidyr, tibble

Having a data frame, I want to generate a new list-column containing named vector(s) (one vector per row). Each vector derives its names and values from 2 other data frame columns. But I'm stuck because I want to do it:

- *by group*
- as computationally-efficient as possible

### Example

Let's take `mpg` dataset from `{ggplot2}` to illustrate the *by group* principle. I want to lump together pairs of `cty` and `hwy` values, grouped by distinct combinations of `manufacturer` & `year`. So we can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

my_mpg <-
  mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer, year, cty, hwy)

via_tidyr_nest <- 
  my_mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  nest()

via_tidyr_nest
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year [30]
#>    manufacturer  year data             
#>    <chr>        <int> <list>           
#>  1 audi          1999 <tibble [9 x 2]> 
#>  2 audi          2008 <tibble [9 x 2]> 
#>  3 chevrolet     2008 <tibble [12 x 2]>
#>  4 chevrolet     1999 <tibble [7 x 2]> 
#>  5 dodge         1999 <tibble [16 x 2]>
#>  6 dodge         2008 <tibble [21 x 2]>
#>  7 ford          1999 <tibble [15 x 2]>
#>  8 ford          2008 <tibble [10 x 2]>
#>  9 honda         1999 <tibble [5 x 2]> 
#> 10 honda         2008 <tibble [4 x 2]> 
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is perfect except that I don't want a nested tibble but a nested named vector. (*the reason: once we store the output as an object in the environment, the named vector version is lighter in size than the nested tibble one*).

**The working but undesired solution** would take `via_tidyr_nest` and convert the nested tibble into a named vector.

```r
expected_output <-
  via_tidyr_nest %>%
  mutate(desired_named_vec = map(.x = data, .f = ~pull(.x, cty, hwy))) %>%
  select(-data)

expected_output
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year [30]
#>    manufacturer  year desired_named_vec
#>    <chr>        <int> <list>           
#>  1 audi          1999 <int [9]>        
#>  2 audi          2008 <int [9]>        
#>  3 chevrolet     2008 <int [12]>       
#>  4 chevrolet     1999 <int [7]>        
#>  5 dodge         1999 <int [16]>       
#>  6 dodge         2008 <int [21]>       
#>  7 ford          1999 <int [15]>       
#>  8 ford          2008 <int [10]>       
#>  9 honda         1999 <int [5]>        
#> 10 honda         2008 <int [4]>        
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

This is undesired because it achieves the desired output via a detour. First it creates a tibble and then it converts to a named vector. While processing time is negligible in this example, in reality I have a large dataset (10 million rows). Thus, adding any extra step is costly. Instead, I wish to arrive at `expected_output` with as fewest steps as possible.

---

One unsuccessful attempt:

```r
library(purrr)

via_summarise_map2_setnames <- 
  my_mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  summarise(named_vec = map2(.x = cty, .y = hwy, .f = ~setNames(.x, .y))) 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'manufacturer', 'year'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

via_summarise_map2_setnames
#> # A tibble: 234 x 3
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year [30]
#>    manufacturer  year named_vec
#>    <chr>        <int> <list>   
#>  1 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  2 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  3 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  4 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  5 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  6 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  7 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  8 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#>  9 audi          1999 <int [1]>
#> 10 audi          2008 <int [1]>
#> # ... with 224 more rows
```

---

Any idea how to go from `my_mpg` to `expected_output` directly, without creating a tibble in-between?

---

EDIT

---

Just a general thought in the context of this question. I understand that the default behavior of `tidyr::nest()` is to return a nested tibble. But I didn't find any discussion of this decision. In other words, what if we wanted to choose ourselves the class of the nested data? It could be either a `tibble` as default, or otherwise a `data.frame`, `data.table`, `named vector`, etc. Whatever the user chooses as the output class.

Comment: Does `as.list` + setting names get you what you expect from applying it on the tibble?

Comment: @anymous.asker, could you please provide some code to demonstrate what you mean? Not entirely sure I understand.

Comment: What is a "nested named vector"? Do you mean a (named) list of vectors?

Comment: @Till, see `desired_named_vec` in `expected_output` object in the example. Each vector under `desired_named_vec` list-column is a "nested named vector".

Comment: "nested named vector" is not an accurate term for what you are describing, it's a "list of vectors" or a "list column of vectors".

Comment: @Emman. I edited my version for better perfomances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way. Coerce `cty` and `hwy` to `"list"` before setting the names. It seems to work.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")
my_mpg <-
  mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer, year, cty, hwy)

my_mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  summarise(named_vec = map2(list(cty), list(hwy), ~set_names(.x, .y)))
#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'manufacturer'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
## A tibble: 30 x 3
## Groups:   manufacturer [15]
#   manufacturer  year named_vec 
#   <chr>        <int> <list>    
# 1 audi          1999 <int [9]> 
# 2 audi          2008 <int [9]> 
# 3 chevrolet     1999 <int [7]> 
# 4 chevrolet     2008 <int [12]>
# 5 dodge         1999 <int [16]>
# 6 dodge         2008 <int [21]>
# 7 ford          1999 <int [15]>
# 8 ford          2008 <int [10]>
# 9 honda         1999 <int [5]> 
#10 honda         2008 <int [4]> 
## … with 20 more rows
```

---

### Benchmarks

Since the question is a performance question, here are the benchmarks of the 4 proposed solutions, so far, the question's, [Nicolas2's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348238/8245406), [Till's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348601/8245406) and mine above.

```
f <- function(X) {
  X %>%
    group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(desired_named_vec = map(.x = data, .f = ~pull(.x, cty, hwy))) %>%
    select(-data)
}

g <- function(X) {
  df1 <- X %>% group_by(manufacturer, year)
  df2 <- attr(df1,"groups")
  Map(function(rows) {
    r <- df1[rows,"cty",drop=TRUE]
    setNames(r,df1[rows,"hwy",drop=TRUE])
  },
  df2$.rows
  ) -> l
  data.frame(manufacturer=df2$manufacturer,year=df2$year,named_vector=I(l))
}
h <- function(X){
  X %>%
    group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
    summarise(named_vec = map2(list(cty), list(hwy), ~set_names(.x, .y)), .groups = "drop")
}
i <- function(X){
  X |>
    select(manufacturer, year, cty, hwy) |>
    group_by(manufacturer, year)  |>
    group_modify(\(x, ...) tibble(res = list(deframe(x))))
}

mb <- microbenchmark(
  Emman = f(my_mpg),
  Nicolas2 = g(my_mpg),
  Rui = h(my_mpg),
  Till = i(my_mpg)
)
print(mb, unit = "relative", order = "median")
#Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
#      Rui 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100 a   
# Nicolas2 1.527957 1.468524 1.478286 1.482185 1.471565 1.724004   100  b  
#    Emman 4.504185 4.230921 4.215643 4.234087 4.148188 4.170934   100   c 
#     Till 6.264028 5.813678 5.883107 5.810876 5.744080 5.666524   100    d
```

Comment: Please try my improved solution. There seems a huge cost to use map insetad of Map.

Comment: @Nicolas2 Done, but I don't see the cost you have noticed. Have you benchmarked it too?

Comment: This offers the simplest syntax for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr::group_modify()` and `tibble::deframe()` can be used here. Instead of `deframe()` the `pull(x, cty, hwy)` from your question would work just the same.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mpg |>
  select(manufacturer, year, cty, hwy) |>
  group_by(manufacturer, year)  |>
  group_modify(\(x, ...) tibble(res = list(deframe(x))))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 3
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, year [30]
#>    manufacturer  year res       
#>    <chr>        <int> <list>    
#>  1 audi          1999 <int [9]> 
#>  2 audi          2008 <int [9]> 
#>  3 chevrolet     1999 <int [7]> 
#>  4 chevrolet     2008 <int [12]>
#>  5 dodge         1999 <int [16]>
#>  6 dodge         2008 <int [21]>
#>  7 ford          1999 <int [15]>
#>  8 ford          2008 <int [10]>
#>  9 honda         1999 <int [5]> 
#> 10 honda         2008 <int [4]> 
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

edited : replaced 'map' by 'Map'

I hope this can be useful.
Your solution is within 'f', my proposal within 'g'.
It uses the index created by dplyr's 'group_by' to collect the needed data to build the named vectors.

```
f <- function () {
via_tidyr_nest <- 
  my_mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  nest()
expected_output <-
  via_tidyr_nest %>%
  mutate(desired_named_vec = map(.x = data, .f = ~pull(.x, cty, hwy))) %>%
  select(-data)
}

g <- function () {
df1 <- my_mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, year)
df2 <- attr(df1,"groups")
Map(function(rows) {
      r <- df1[rows,"cty",drop=TRUE]
      setNames(r,df1[rows,"hwy",drop=TRUE])
    },
    df2$.rows
  ) -> l
df <- data.frame(manufacturer=df2$manufacturer,year=df2$year,named_vector=I(l))
}

# other solutions
h <- function () {
hdf <- my_mpg %>%
  group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
  summarise(named_vec = map2(list(cty), list(hwy), ~set_names(.x, .y)))
}

k <- function() {
mpg |>
  select(manufacturer, year, cty, hwy) |>
  group_by(manufacturer, year)  |>
  group_modify(\(x, ...) tibble(res = list(deframe(x))))
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP=f(),Nicolas2=g(),Rui=h(),Till=k())
Unit: milliseconds
     expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
       OP 21.8917 22.64035 24.389126 23.28235 24.70075  39.9593   100
 Nicolas2  3.0507  3.15920  3.481469  3.24625  3.57840   7.3173   100
      Rui  6.5460  6.75300  7.505564  7.16255  7.64390  12.0359   100
     Till 31.2364 32.31115 34.940356 32.92990 36.11505 107.2709   100
```

Comment: Thanks. Running your solution gives me an [unusual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1jbx.png). If I try to convert to `tibble` using `tibble::as_tibble()`, I get this [strange class *`<I<list>>`*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ7Ci.png). Any idea how to make this output compatible with other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

So far, @RuiBarradas's solution is the speediest. I came up with a `data.table` version of it, which seems to improve speed a bit.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(data.table, warn.conflicts = FALSE)


my_mpg <-
  mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer, year, hwy, cty)

my_mpg %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  .[,.(named_vec = map2(.x = list(cty), .y = list(hwy), .f = ~setNames(.x, .y))),.(manufacturer, year)] %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 30 x 3
#>    manufacturer  year named_vec 
#>    <chr>        <int> <list>    
#>  1 audi          1999 <int [9]> 
#>  2 audi          2008 <int [9]> 
#>  3 chevrolet     2008 <int [12]>
#>  4 chevrolet     1999 <int [7]> 
#>  5 dodge         1999 <int [16]>
#>  6 dodge         2008 <int [21]>
#>  7 ford          1999 <int [15]>
#>  8 ford          2008 <int [10]>
#>  9 honda         1999 <int [5]> 
#> 10 honda         2008 <int [4]> 
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

### Benchmarking

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(data.table, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

my_mpg <-
  mpg %>%
  select(manufacturer, year, cty, hwy)


f <- function(X) {
  X %>%
    group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(desired_named_vec = map(.x = data, .f = ~pull(.x, cty, hwy))) %>%
    select(-data)
}

g <- function(X) {
  df1 <- my_mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer, year)
  df2 <- attr(df1,"groups")
  Map(function(rows) {
    r <- df1[rows,"cty",drop=TRUE]
    setNames(r,df1[rows,"hwy",drop=TRUE])
  },
  df2$.rows
  ) -> l
  data.frame(manufacturer=df2$manufacturer,year=df2$year,named_vector=I(l))
}
h <- function(X){
  X %>%
    group_by(manufacturer, year) %>%
    summarise(named_vec = map2(list(cty), list(hwy), ~set_names(.x, .y)), .groups = "drop")
}
i <- function(X){
  X |>
    select(manufacturer, year, cty, hwy) |>
    group_by(manufacturer, year)  |>
    group_modify(\(x, ...) tibble(res = list(deframe(x))))
}

j <- function(X){
  X %>%
    as.data.table() %>%
    .[,.(named_vec = map2(.x = list(cty), .y = list(hwy), .f = ~setNames(.x, .y))),.(manufacturer, year)] %>%
    as_tibble()
}

library(microbenchmark)
library(bench)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  Emman_OP = f(my_mpg),
  Nicolas2 = g(my_mpg),
  Rui = h(my_mpg),
  Till = i(mpg),
  Emman_data.table_version_of_Rui = j(my_mpg)
)
print(mb, unit = "relative", order = "median")
#> Unit: relative
#>                             expr       min        lq      mean    median
#>  Emman_data.table_version_of_Rui  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
#>                              Rui  2.472627  2.457073  2.392998  2.409865
#>                         Nicolas2  3.317832  3.317378  3.116434  3.295358
#>                         Emman_OP 10.255926 10.472251  9.842886 10.674290
#>                             Till 14.061003 14.333661 13.115049 14.937978
#>         uq      max neval
#>   1.000000 1.000000   100
#>   2.395210 2.191381   100
#>   3.258533 2.719938   100
#>  10.572811 5.331644   100
#>  14.086673 5.418907   100
```

Nicely, the `data.table` adaptation to @Rui's is the fastest.

But!

If we look at memory allocation (which is another aspect of performance):

```r
bm <- bench::mark(Emman_OP = f(my_mpg),
                  Nicolas2 = g(my_mpg),
                  Rui = h(my_mpg),
                  Till = i(mpg),
                  Emman_data.table_version_of_Rui = j(my_mpg), check = FALSE)

summary(bm, relative = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   expression                        min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>                      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Emman_OP                        12.0   11.8       1.24     13.8      1.18
#> 2 Nicolas2                         3.75   3.67      3.84      1        1.08
#> 3 Rui                              2.77   2.76      5.18      1.49     1.06
#> 4 Till                            15.1   15.7       1         7.10     1.45
#> 5 Emman_data.table_version_of_Rui  1      1        14.3       7.53     1
```

we can see that @Nicols2 is the lightest, @Rui's original is also pretty good, but my data.table version is not so much. I wonder why, and whether there's a way to make `data.table` run more efficiently also in the memory allocation aspect.