# Preparing non-equal length or sample freq time series for dtwclust

Tags: r, time, series, hierarchical-clustering, tsibble

Looking for assistance on how to prepare multiple time series of varying length (and sampling frequency) for clustering with the `dtwclust` package in R. Note that my series are at 15 or 30 minute sampling frequencies and the date/time isn't relevant so just storing as minute index.

From looking at the ?tslist  constructor, I need to create a list of time series.

I currently have the data in long format in a R data.table, toy example below:

```
structure(list(new_id = structure(c("4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "4f755b0b0ba498f2d2e00c7951eaaeb9", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", "a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312", 
"a73d5cf68dee23eb83d5a8a59ac22312"), class = c("hash", "md5")), 
    value = c(500, 2400, 500, 2200, 500, 1400, 400, 600, 300, 
    900, 200, 800, 200, 800, 175, 800, 900, 600, 1700, 1700, 
    800, 700, 850, 750, 600, 500, 400, 350), elapsed_time = c(15, 
    10, 30, 20, 45, 30, 60, 40, 75, 50, 90, 60, 105, 70, 120, 
    80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 
    200)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001cfcb878c00>)
```

I feel like I've tried a few ideas but not successfully created the correct data structure.
I started looking at tsibble but it doesn't look like the object can be coerced into tslist.
Is there a way to do this with data.table or the *pply family?

Really appreciate any guidance - I have searched but not found a close enough solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found a related question and could work from that.
[How to generate a list-column holding named-vectors, when grouping by other data frame variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69347585/how-to-generate-a-list-column-holding-named-vectors-when-grouping-by-other-data)

There may be a more elegant solution than this, but will put here for anyone in same predicament as me.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    toy_res =   toy %>%
      group_by(new_id) %>%
      summarise(named_vec = map2(list(value), list(elapsed_time),
~set_names(.x, .y)), .groups = "drop")
    
    t_list <- toy_res$named_vec
    names(t_list) = toy_res$new_id
```

t_list can now be used in dtwclust - except in this toy case because I only provided two series it will error. In my larger dataset it works.

Actually - it 'works' but does not honor the timestamp names in each vector. This answer is still a WIP.